# Why is lubridate adding 1 second to an 'MS' (minute-second) time with a decimal after converting?

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

When I have no decimal, it is fine:

```
time = parse_date_time('5:55', 'MS')
second(time)
# 55
```

When I add a decimal, it is off by 1

```
time = parse_date_time('5:55.34', 'MS')
second(time)
# 56.34
```

It obviously detects the decimal place I originally had, but it seems to be still rounding the unit digit up by one.

Is this intended behavior?

**Extra Information:**

- This occurs in both versions `1.7.1` and `1.7.3` on Windows 10
- This occurs in `1.7.1`on Mac OS Sierra

Comment: Why are you not using `;` in format part too?

Comment: This might be a bug in `parse_date_time`. I originally thought it was a rounding error introduced by `as.POSIXlt(time)$sec` operation but I've now discovered that this behavior happens in all cases. Since default behavior of lubridate is to round up, I can only imagine that it does not know how to deal with millisecond formats, and that `MS` is minutes and seconds but no decimals are expected. I tried various options for fractional seconds and it still adds that ghost second. This is frustrating! You already know that :)

Comment: Are you sure you are running the latest version of lubridate? When I run exactly the same command, I get the correct result 55.34 (packageVersion("lubridate") returns "1.7.3")

Comment: I was running `1.7.1`, but when I upgraded to `1.7.3`, I still got that error.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be using `ms`?

```r
library(lubridate)

time = ms('5:55.34')
second(time)
#[1] 55.34
```